# Twisted reactor.listenUNIX erroring after update to python 3.8

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

I have updated twisted from 13.0.0 to 20.3.0 and python from 2.7 to 3.8 and now twisted is throwing this not helpful error. (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS)

I verified the permissions of the .sock file and the directory, made sure the socket file is deleted before `reactor.listenUNIX` is called.

What could be the cause of this and how can I troubleshoot this issue?

```py
class UserServer(Plugin):
    def setup(self):
        socket = self.parent.socket
        if os.path.exists(socket):
            os.remove(socket)
        self.console(socket)
        self.console(self.parent.config.get_umask('sock'))
        self.factory = UserServerFactory(self.parent)
        reactor.listenUNIX(socket, self.factory, mode=self.parent.config.get_umask('sock'))
```

```
service: 'user_server' failed to initialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mcgen/tools/mark2/mk2/plugins/__init__.py", line 335, in load
    plugin = cls(self.parent, name, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mcgen/tools/mark2/mk2/plugins/__init__.py", line 165, in __init__
    self.setup()
  File "/home/mcgen/tools/mark2/mk2/services/user_server.py", line 148, in setup
    reactor.listenUNIX(socket, self.factory, mode=self.parent.config.get_umask('sock'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 397, in listenUNIX
    p.startListening()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/twisted/internet/unix.py", line 408, in startListening
    self.startReading()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/twisted/internet/abstract.py", line 435, in startReading
    self.reactor.addReader(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 109, in addReader
    self._add(reader, self._reads, self._writes, self._selectables,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/twisted/internet/epollreactor.py", line 96, in _add
    self._poller.register(fd, flags)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Twisted 20.3 doesn't claim to support Python 3.8.  Try Python 3.7.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone I'm having the same issue with Python 3.7.9

Comment: Okay.  The next step is probably to create a complete, self-contained, minimal example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example